# Unable to update Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04

I am unable to download the latest version of Ubuntu

I  am getting below error:

The required dependency 'dpkg (>= 1.17.5ubuntu5.6)' is not installed.

i have tried everything about updating and downloading the dpkg package but its still getting the same here.

Can someone please help?

Comment: You really need to give us what you've tried so far: what commands you've run, what produced this error, what "everything" you've tried, etc. You obviously haven't tried everything, otherwise this would be working, but it'd be nice to avoid suggesting what you have done.

Comment: @OrganicMarble how is this a duplicate of that question? The target question is about `apt`, this is about `dpkg`!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb     - Download File link

Step 2 :

```
sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
```

Then trigger the update again by:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```